# Future of email sending from Windows desktop application

Tags: email, visual-foxpro, foxpro, email-client, cdo.message

Sergey CDO class

https://www.berezniker.com/content/pages/visual-foxpro/cdo-2000-class-sending-emails

is used to send emails.

CDO is no longer supprted:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/collaboration-data-objects-cdo-1-2-1-is-not-supported-with-outlook-2010-and-later-versions-268ce809-7923-95ba-2c70-3f23569f57eb

How to send e-mails from Visual FoxPro 9 Desktop application using supported method ?

Comment: I am using a Golang based sender. It is very simple but custom built, I send to it a json structure containing information encrypted and it does the rest. You might as well use an activex build with C#. It is simple. For a sample check this https://www.foxite.com/archives/check-if-a-windows-service-is-running-0000485037.htm

Comment: This requires creating c# wrapper ActiveX and its registering. Using Sergey CDO2000 class allows to use only FoxPro code. blat.dll also works but it doesnt support SSL connections. Where to find solution in VFP which does not require programming in other language?

Comment: I have never seen one VFP solution yet. All I have seen and used were based on other languages (be it C++ based FLL, C# based activex ...). Creating and registering a C# based activex is simple (check the link I supplied). Writing one in Golang is also simple and looks like using blat with SSL etc built-in. I used one from a well known web tools provider for VFP but it created problems for us in debugging, so I sorted to write my own.

Comment: BTW CDO doesn't only use VFP code. It is also an activex.

Comment: There is Sergey VFP class which calls CDO directly. No maintaining other language code is required. User has no rights to register ActiveX control. How to send emails without ActiveX registration rights?

Comment: You can have the activex in the same folder as your exe or create a manifest. There is nothing wrong in registering an activex and it is the proper way to use it.

Comment: Can you provide sample how to use this in VFP application

Comment: I gave the link above - https://www.foxite.com/archives/check-if-a-windows-service-is-running-0000485037.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CDO then you're sending via Outlook, so why not just automate Outlook directly ?

```
loOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
loMessage = loOutlook.CreateItem(0)

loMessage.Subject = "test email 1"
loMessage.Recipients.Add("recipient@company.com")
loMessage.BodyFormat = 2        && 2 = html 3 = rtf
lcHtmlBody = "<html><body>This is the body text.</body></html>"
loMessage.HTMLBody = lcHtmlbody
loMessage.Send()
```

Comment: CDO does not use outlook. Outlook is not installed in client computers.